# How to generate Apple-style /// for code comments in Xcode?

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, documentation

I'm trying to find a more efficient way to generate the Apple-style /// code comments in Xcode.

Although I can use Cmd + Option + Enter to automatically generate ///, it's not as convenient when copying(press option to select specific area) and pasting code. Is there a more streamlined approach to generate these comments, especially when pasting existing code?

[image: Apple Style Code Comment Documetation]

It's convenient to generate doc with old /** */

[image: Old Style]

Comment: So you want to copy and paste code into the comments? I'm not sure what you are trying to do

Comment: Yes, I want to paste some existing example code into /// comment to generate DocC documentation.